# How to re-create a "crosstab plot" showing proportions using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would greatly appreciate any help with re-creating this "crosstab plot" showing proportions:

[image]
(source: [PEW](https://www.pewresearch.org/religion/2022/05/06/americas-abortion-quandary/pf_05-06-22_abortion-views_0_3/))

I guess the way is to use geom_point with the appropriate shape, but I cant really get any further than this

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame (col  = c("A","A","B","B"),
                  row = c("C", "D","C","D"),
                  val = c(4,10,29,31))

ggplot(df, aes(y = row, x = col)) + geom_point(size = df$val, shape = 15)
```

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think `geom_rect()` might be more appropriate than `geom_point()` for this purpose. To get this to work, one first needs to decide what goes on the left/right, top/bottom of the plot. Below, we do that by finding a sign for a category.

```r
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame (col  = c("A","A","B","B"),
                  row = c("C", "D","C","D"),
                  val = c(4,10,29,31))

df <- transform(
  df,
  sign_col = ifelse(col == "A", -1, 1),
  sign_row = ifelse(row == "C", -1, 1)
)
```

Then you can multiply the sign with coordinates to get the plot you might like.

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_rect(
    aes(xmin = 0, xmax = sign_col * val,
        ymin = 0, ymax = sign_row * val,
        fill = factor(val))
  ) +
  geom_text(
    aes(label = val,
        x = 0.5 * sign_col * val,
        y = 0.5 * sign_row * val)
  ) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>